# How can I continue executing commands on a splitted terminal window with Vim?

Tags: vimscript, terminal

Let's say I run the following command on a node.js file inside Vim:

```
:terminal node %"
```

[image]

I'd like to continue executing commands on the newly opened window with a single command. But if I try executing `:terminal node % | w! /tmp/file | e /tmp/file` it doesn't work. Even though running first `:terminal node %` and then `:w! /tmp/file | e /tmp/file` manually it works.

Inside vimscript if I try using:

```
:terminal node %
:w! /tmp/file | e /tmp/file
```

It also doesn't work. What am I missing? How can execute commands on the new window opened by the `terminal` command?

Answer (score 1):

The command `:terminal` includes `|` in its arguments (so that you can run a pipeline). See `:help :terminal`:

```
            No Vim command can follow, any | is included in
            [command].  Use `:execute` if you must have a Vim
            command following in the same line.
```

The standard trick around this is to instead

```
:execute 'terminal node %' | write! /tmp/file | edit /tmp/file
```

Comment: Even though it executes using the command like that it seems that it doesn't wait for the execution of `terminal node %` to finish to start executing the next commands. I've realized that using `execute 'terminal node %' | sleep 1 | w! /tmp/file | e /tmp/file` works filne for a simple `console.log('Hello World')` example. But not all codes will finish after 1 second. Is there any way of starting `write! /tmp/file` only after `terminal node %` finished its execution?

Comment: @raylight you get more programmatic control if you use the `term_start` or `job_start` functions